# How to Guide Users to Upgrade from One VSCode Theme to Another?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm seeking advice on an issue related to VSCode themes. Previously, I published a theme called luke-dark-theme, and recently, I released a new theme called Photonica. Photonica is intended to be a direct upgrade from luke-dark-theme.

I am wondering if there is a way to facilitate users who have installed luke-dark-theme to easily or automatically upgrade to the new Photonica theme. How can I do this?

Comment: Love the new Photonica theme btw. I already switched from my old theme.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode has a feature to deprecate extensions and warn + guide users to install the alternative.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions/1

Quote from the announcement:

> We now support deprecating extensions.
>
> An extension can be just deprecated or deprecated in favour of another
> extension or a setting. If a deprecated extension has this alternative
> extension or a setting the UI will guide users to migrate to the new
> extension or setting.
>
> For now the extension will not be rendered as deprecated in the
> Marketplace. Support for this will come later.
>
> In order to mark your extension as deprecated please reach out to us.
> You can also comment in this discussion.

For example:

[image: vscode deprecate extension]